# TypeScript Karma Jamsine Test "exports is not defined" with simpletsc preprocessor

Tags: typescript, npm, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In order to learn how to create my own NPM module, I'm first trying to create a simple NPM module written in TypeScript that would just provide an interface & class that has a very simple method sayHi() that just returns "Hello World". I wanted to try creating the module so that I could pull it into an Angular 2 app using NPM and then try calling the method.

The build to the dist folder works fine and it is able to be pulled into a sample Angular 2 application and used without any problems.

I wanted to make sure that my code was tested, so I tried adding the Karma spec runner using the Jasmine framework. I followed the Karma [installation guide](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/installation.html) and initialized my Karma.conf.js and finally, I added the [Simple TSC Preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-simpletsc-preprocessor) to process the TypeScript files. The problem is that when I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
  at index.js:10
```

All the code and settings can be found on GitHub at https://github.com/holotrek/hello-world-npm-module

Comment: I'm still not sure why this is happening, but I ended up changing my preprocessor from karma-simpletsc-preprocessor to karma-typescript, which did not work in 2.1.7, but their brand new version 3.0.0 fixed the problem. See my updated GitHub project for the fix. (Note that the karma-webpack and karma-tsc-preprocessor had the same problem, so it appears to be a widely distributed issue.)